# I am getting error in sending argument with space

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am sending argument from my iphone application to php page to genrate xml given below.

```
feedurl=@"http://www.abc.net/feed/index_clatest.php?more=s-laday gaga";
```

The url run in mozila when it runs.

but when i run it in my iphone application i get the following error.

**erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSConcreteData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]: nil URL*

Note: it works when i just send s-lady in argument.

Help me please.

Comment: The url run in mozila when it runs. - Captain Obvious.

And Lady Gaga, what the heckkkk :D?

Comment: @Jordy: that's because Mozilla will percent escape the URL for you if you type it into the address bar.

Comment: @JeremyP you understand i was laughing about Lady gaga :D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to replace space (and other invalid in url characters) by percent escapes. NSString has `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method for that

Comment: To add a little more explanation to this correct but short answer, the string @"http://www.abc.net/feed/index_clatest.php?more=s-laday gaga" is not a valid URL because it contains a space.  Cocoa validates URLs before trying to use them.